# Scrolling to top after i making selection React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, frontend

I'm trying in Multi-Select dropdown scrolls to top after making a selection, so the last items I selected it should be in the top of the dropdown. So any idea how can I do it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-field-vitr9r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey there so from what I can see is that the names that you are mapping through in the children section of the Select is that it seems that the way material is working is that it is using the order of the names in the list that you provide called names and whatever that array of names positioning is is the way the values will be represented I dont know why they do it like this But it basically amends the array every time no matter how you try change it 

The solution is to rather have a select where you can select the values but then store them differently

Comment: Maybe use something like the customSelect and handle all the logic your self to append an item to the beginning of an array either user const newArray = [...array].unShift(value) or const newArray = [value, ...array] hope this helps

Comment: @kodamaceThank you for your helping out. I will try it.